# Instagraph API(Insights) - (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When ever I try to hit this :

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841401441775531/insights?metric=impressions,reach&access_token=token

It gives me :

{
"error": {
"message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 10,
"fbtrace_id": "Adtcj8kWP-s0YyvvYzyxb8S"
}
}

{ig-user-id} being used here is of the random business account on Instagram with followers more than 100.

The app is in development phase. Could we fetch the insights of different business account? If yes what am I doing wrong, please suggest.

I tried with my {ig-user-id}, it returns the insights. But I want of the other business accounts.